# Is there a 2d function that will satisfy this group by requirement on two columns or is there a more sql way to do?

Tags: sql, sqlite, math, group-by

I have a table and need to do a group by over two columns or a function of those that yields the expected grouping criteria. This became surprisingly an interesting math challenge but I am also happy to see how to solve it in a standard SQL solution.

I have the following table:

```
create table temp (a integer, x integer, y integer);
insert into temp values (3, 0, 1);
insert into temp values (3, 1, -1);
insert into temp values (4, 0, 1);
insert into temp values (4, 1, -1);
insert into temp values (4, 0, -1);
insert into temp values (4, 1, 1);
```

I'd like to group together rows:

- 1 and 2
- 3 and 4
- 5 and 6

Therefore, the select would be:

```
select a
from temp
group by a, f(x, y)
```

For that I need a function `f(x, y)` built on available SQLite integer operators i.e. *, +, -, / therefore I need a function such that:

- f(0, 1) = f(1, -1) and
- f(0, -1) = f(1, 1)

  I have tried multiple possibilities but can't figure out such grouping function ... any clever ideas? :)

Would there be an alternative SQL solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can define such a "function" using a `case` expression:

```
(case when x = 0 and y = 1 then 1
      when x = 1 and y = -1 then 1
      when x = 0 and y = -1 then 2
      when x = 1 and y = 1 then 2
 end)
```

If you want an arithmetic expression:

```
(2 * x * y - y)
```